# What is the worst case accuracy for dot product?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

Suppose the processor has only 'fadd' and 'fmul' operations (no 'dot' or 'fma' instructions) which are IEEE-754 compliant. What is the worst case accuracy that will be achieved by the trivial implemention of the dot product operation. For example, for a vector of length 3:

```
dot(vec_a, vec_b) = vec_a.x*vec_b.x + vec_a.y*vec_b.y + vec_a.z*vec_b.z
```

Here is my analysis, but I am not sure if it correct:
For a vector of length N, there are N multiplications and N-1 additions, resulting in 2N-1 floating point operations. In the worst case, for each of these operations the representation will be too small for the accurate result, so the intermediate result will be rounded. Each rounding adds up to 0.5 ULP error. So the maximum error will be (2N-1)*0.5 = N-1/2 ULP?

Comment: Are you sorting the vector of products before summing it, using e.g. Kahan summation, or simply summing it directly? How you do the summation affects the worst case error in that step.

Comment: Products are computed arbitrarily by order of elements. Can't trade off run time for accuracy

Answer (score 5):

Your reasoning does not work for additions: if `a` and `b` are already inaccurate by 0.5 ULP each and `a` is close to `-b`, then the relative accuracy of `a + b` can be [terrible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance), much worse than 1.5 ULP. In fact, without further information about the vectors you are computing the dot-product of, there are no guarantees one can provide about the relative accuracy of the result.

Your line of reasoning is okay-ish when there are only multiplications, but it ignores compounded errors.

Consider the equation: (a + e<sub>a</sub>)(b + e<sub>b</sub>) = ab + ae<sub>b</sub> + be<sub>a</sub> + e<sub>a</sub>e<sub>b</sub>.

If you assume that both a and b are between 1 and 2, the total relative error after multiplication of two results that were already accurate to 0.5 ULP each can only, in a rough first approximation, be estimated as 1 ULP, and that is still ignoring the error term e<sub>a</sub>e<sub>b</sub> and the error of the multiplication itself. Make it about 1.5 ULP total relative error for the result of the floating-point multiplication, and this is only a rough average, not a sound maximum.

These [colleagues of mine](http://toccata.lri.fr/gallery/ScalarProduct.en.html) have formalized and demonstrated a notion of accuracy of the double-precision floating-point dot-product. A translation to English of their result is that if each vector component is bounded by `1.0`, then the end result of the dot product is accurate to NMAX * B, where NMAX is the dimension of the vectors, and B is a constant depending on NMAX. A few values are provided on the linked page:

```
NMAX     10            100            1000
B        0x1.1p-50     0x1.02p-47     0x1.004p-44
```

In their result, you can substitute `1.0` with any **power of two** P low enough to ensure the absence of overflow, and the absolute error of the dot product then becomes NMAX * B * P<sup>2</sup>. The loop invariants become respectively:

```
@ loop invariant \abs(exact_scalar_product(x,y,i)) <= i * P * P;
@ loop invariant \abs(p - exact_scalar_product(x,y,i)) <= i * B * P * P;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my wrong assumption. What would be a good way to describe the worst case error? Maybe error relative to the max element in vec_a and vec_b?

Comment: @zr. Is there anything you can say about the vectors, e.g. each component of one vector always has the same sign as the corresponding component of the other vector (for instance, if all components of all vectors being manipulated were positive, it would imply this)? Without any additional information, I think it is very difficult to characterize the total error over such a complex operation as the dot product as either a single relative error statistic or an absolute error one.

Comment: @PC There are no limitations on the input values. Is there at least some upper bound that can be used for sanity testing? EDIT: I will look at the paper, thank!

Comment: The usual error bound used for dot products in numerical analysis is the backwards error bound which involves the norms of the vectors (this is looser than the more accurate bound that Sneftel references, or the even more accurate bound that Pascal gives here, but totally sufficient for most mathematical purposes).

Comment: The relative error may be arbitrarily large, but the absolute error will be bounded by the sum of the maximum absolute errors present in the earlier calculations.  If one expects a result which is between -100 and +100, and needs it accurate to +/- 0.1 units, and if the worst-case absolute errors would sum to 0.037, a naive approach will be fine.  If the result comes out to 0.0001274, the relative error may be enormous, but if all results between -0.05 and +0.05 would be considered equivalent, that wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

As with many  FP error analyses, the error is strongly dependent on the maximum magnitude of the input. In this case, a rough-and-ready error bound is `2 * FLT_EPS * dot(abs(vec_a), abs(vec_b))`, where `abs` denotes the elementwise absolute value of the vector.

Comment: Can you please why the above expression is an upper bound?

Comment: The detailed proof can be found in *Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms*, by Nicholas Higham. Briefly, the dot product is three FP operations "deep", and involves addends of magnitude up to that of the absolute dot product.

Comment: (Note: That means that the constant factor can be tightened from 2 to slightly more than 1.5. I tend to round up my FP error bound constant factors, though, to ensure that the bounds computation itself isn't subject to problematic rounding.)